# How to show LocalNotifications repeat status in Table View Cell?

Tags: tableview, repeat

My app has local notifications . It works perfectly fine . I use the Table view controller so show the active notification . The problem i am facing is that in the table view cell , it doesn't show that if the notification is set to repeat or when it will repeat (i.e., every hour , every day etc) .

The code for the table cell that show the details about every notifications is below :

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
  {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
  TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  // Get list of local notifications

  localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
  UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:localNotification.fireDate
                                                        dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle
                                                        timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
  NSString *timeString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:localNotification.fireDate
                                                        dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle
                                                        timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

  cell.TitleLabel.text = localNotification.alertBody;
  cell.DateLabel.text = dateString;
  cell.TimeLabel.text = timeString;
  cell.repeatStatus.text =localNotification.repeatInterval;

  cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

  return cell;

}

i tried a lot of things , but nothing is working out . Please help .

Thanks in advance.